# How can I check that an artifact is built in ADO

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I'm building an ADO pipeline and want to check that an artifact has been created before continuing with the build stage. I'm trying to create a variable to tell me if the file exists but when I run the pipeline I get an error saying the file path is invalid.

This is the relevant ymal code:

```
        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

        inputs: 

          PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) # dist or build files

          ArtifactName: 'www' # output artifact named www

        

      - task: PowerShell@2

        inputs:

          script: |

            $fileExists = Test-Path -Path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/www/dist/apps/poc/index.html"

            Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FileExists]$fileExists"

 

- stage: deploy

  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['FileExists'], True))
```

This is the error that I get when I run the pipeline:

> ##[error]Invalid file path '/home/vsts/work/1/s'. A path to a .ps1 file is required.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?

Answer (score 0):

> ##[error]Invalid file path '/home/vsts/work/1/s'. A path to a .ps1 file is required.

From your YAML sample, the Powershell task definition format is not correct if you are using inline script type.

You need to define the **targetType** field.

For example: `targetType: 'inline'`

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $fileExists = Test-Path -Path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/www/dist/apps/poc/index.html"
      
      Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FileExists]$fileExists"
```

Comment: Thanks, that prevented the error. However, I still have a problem that the fileExists variable is false even when I can see the artifact is there. Is there something wrong with how I've constructed the path to my artifact?

Comment: @LeoFarmer You can try to remove the `www` in the path and check if it can work. For example: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist/apps/poc/index.html`

Comment: And i suggest that you can use stage level variable:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-to-stage-dependencies